# Working Principle behind Web Operating Systems?

Tags: operating-system, web-operating-system

I have one query on which I would like to get your valuable feedback.  Nowadays I hear a lot about Web Operating Systems. Like, Google is working on Chrome OS, but I am not sure how OS principles will work with a Web Operating System. I mean, Web OS's will come in picture once the Internet is connected, but for booting up system and other related task we would need an OS and I think a Web OS won't be useful there.

I would really appreciate if someone can point me to useful resources or explain me about the working principle behind a Web Operating System?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll start with the obvious: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_operating_system